# How to read linked entities in ALM 12.53

Tags: alm, hp-alm

I am integrating ServiceNow and ALM with REST APIs.

I am able to read defect data through API from ALM. But I need to read test ids as well which is present in linked entities. I am not familiar with ALM before.

I checked this resource, https://admhelp.microfocus.com/alm/en/12.53/api_refs/REST/webframe.htm#Overview.htm but did not get anything regarding linked entities.

Please suggest a solution.

Thanks,
Ali

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you need, but here is a [link for REST technical preview](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/alm/en/12.55/api_refs/REST_TECH_PREVIEW/ALM_REST_API_TP.html#REST_API_Tech_Preview/General/relations_btwn_entities.htm%3FTocPath%3DHow%2520to%2520Do%2520Common%2520Tasks%7CQuery%2520a%2520Collection%2520of%2520Entities%7C_____2) which contains some info on getting related entities with REST API.